# $this->form_validation->run() returns FALSE without validation rules

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

When using CodeIgniter's `Form_validation` class, the `set_rules()` method allows a user to add an infinite number of checks to their form fields. These rules are usually all defined in the same place, right before the `run()` method is called.

**VALID EXAMPLE**:

```
// Require the user to be a werewolf.
$this->form_validation->set_rules('werewolf', 'Are you a Werewolf?', 'required');

// If the form validates.
if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    // [...]
```

(no, I do not actually run a werewolf website)

The code makes a lot of sense, and is very easy to understand. However, at times, it may be undesirable. For example, perhaps you don't care if the user is a werewolf *unless it is midnight*. Your code would probably look like this:

**INVALID EXAMPLE**

```
// If it is midnight.
if (date('G') == '0')
{
    // Require the user to be a werewolf.
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('werewolf', 'Are you a Werewolf?', 'required');
}

// If the form validates.
if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    // [...]
```

---

## THIS *WON'T WORK*

At least, it won't work until midnight.

By default, `$this->form_validation->run()` returns `FALSE` if there aren't any rules declared. In the second example, unless it's midnight, there will not be any rules set, so the form will never validate. Logically, one would assume that if there are no rules, the form should validate no matter what. Instead, it *fails* no matter what.

**/system/libraries/Form_validation :: run()**

(lines 293-297)

```
// No validation rules?  We're done...
if (count($this->_config_rules) == 0)
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

My question is:

**Why is this the default return value? Is it okay if I change it?**

Comment: You usually don't want to validate when you have no rules to put the data up against. Returning FALSE in this case states that something went wrong: that there was no 'rules' found. I can see this could be useful when working with dynamic rulesets (not that I can think of any use for those).

Comment: In my case, I was trying to require a field if, and only if, a file was submitted along with the form. I was quite worried when I realized I had to change a system function without the internet's approval!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nathanael - you are right, I can't recall without looking if this has been addressed in V3 or no.

Two ways of dealing with this:

1) (this won't work the way your code is currently set up, but w/ a small teak it will) - Set "trim" on every field, all the time. This will trigger all the validation code. It is an old workaround for repopulating forms even when you don't want to make anything required.

2) Better - make a custom rule for that field that is ALWAYS checked, and require it conditionally inside the rule.

Remember that validation library rules are actually just functions on the lib, so inside your custom rule you can do:

```
$this->validation->required($str);
```

type code to check your input.

Comment: Using "trim" is a great solution, despite being a bit hackish. I'll wait around to see if someone can address the issue regarding lines 293-297 before selecting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just set empty rule, the validation lib will auto by pass it and continue.

$this->form_validation->run() will return true instead.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(fieldName,'','');
```

reference https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/1558

Take your code as example, your code will be like this

```
// If it is midnight.
if (date('G') == '0') {
    // Require the user to be a werewolf.
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('werewolf', 'Are you a Werewolf?', 'required');
} else {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('werewolf', '', '');
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution too. Thanks for adding it.